# How can i use the ionic 2 's components in angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to use the ionic 2 in a feature module of my angular 2 project. I want to use the ionic's component or tag in some component of mine. Every things I have done,but I got this error 
`EXCEPTION: Expected to not be in Angular Zone, but it is!`

Can someone tell me how to use the ionic 2 's components in angular 2 project but not to use the ionic-cli to create a new one?

Answer (score 2):

First create an angular 2 project using

```
ng new myapp --style=scss
```

then

```
cd myapp
npm install --save ionic-angular ionicons
```

You may get a few warnings such as

```
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.1 but none was installed.
...
```

It will work even with the warnings but if you prefer to getting rid of all those warnings you can check what peerDependencies are declared by ionic-angular with:

```
npm view ionic-angular peerDependencies
```

Then update the versions in package.json accordingly and `npm install.`
You could also remove @angular/router since Ionic provides its own navigation mechanism.

```
npm uninstall --save @angular/router
```

Then `ng serve`

The next step to use Ionic in your project is to change src/app/app.module.ts to import the IonicModule instead of Angular’s BrowserModule, and bootstrap IonicApp:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ IonicApp ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The IonicApp component has ion-app as its selector, so you also need to modify src/index.html replacing  with .

To keep the project structure somewhat similar to what the Ionic CLI generates, create a src/theme folder, then download and put into that folder these two files: ionic.scss and variables.scss.

Finally include them in build process by editing angular-cli.json to load variables.scss first in the styles inside app:

```
"styles": [
  "theme/variables.scss",
  "styles.scss"
],
```

Note that you’ll have to restart ng serve for this change to take effect.

The final step for having a basic Ionic app is to create a page component, and load it in AppComponent using ion-nav.

To do that create a src/pages folder with a home.page.ts file containing e.g.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  message = 'Welcome!';

}
```

and the corresponding template in home.page.html with a basic Ionic page, including header and content:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic App</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  {{ message }}
</ion-content>
```

You can get the full documentation from [ionic2-with-angular-cli](https://labs.encoded.io/2016/11/12/ionic2-with-angular-cli/) .Hope it helps.